# Mouse coords not available when called from within another function

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I was reorganizing some code to make variables visible to various functions.  I had a function called `getMouseXY` which worked fine when the function was in the global environment (not called from another function).  However, when I put this function inside another function, it gave an error: `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` which I determined was coming from `d3.mouse(this)`.  I asked the console what 'this' was and it is the window, which seems reasonable.  As an alternative, I tried to use the `.pageX` approach and this works but with the wrong coordinates. I can fix that if necessary, but I just don't see why my original approach fails in this situation.  I'm sorry this is not a working example, but can anyone explain why the error is thrown?  `activateGuides` is called from the main thread.  Here is the code:

```
var activateGuides = function() { // controls the guides (cursor) in the contour area

    var getMouseXY = function() { // get the mouse coordinates & report in terms of [0...1] in the contour area
    // var mouse = d3.mouse(this); // error: undefined, but this = window
    // mX = mouse[0];
    // mY = mouse[1];
    mX = d3.event.pageX; // this approach works with slightly wrong coords
    mY = d3.event.pageY;
    mX = mX - lPad // offset reference point (ul corner of contour is 0,0)
    mY = mY - tPad
    if (mX < 0) {mX = 0}; // truncate low
    if (mY < 0) {mY = 0};
    if (mX > conWidth) {mX = conWidth}; // truncate high
    if (mY > conHeight) {mY = conHeight};
    mX = mX/conWidth // as fraction
    mY = mY/conHeight
    followMouse(mX, mY); // draws guidelines at the mouse position
    document.Show.mouseX.value = mX; 
    document.Show.mouseY.value = mY;
    } // end of getMouseXY

} // end of activateGuides
```

Comment: try just event.x and event.y

Comment: @dandavis Thank you for that suggestion, it works better and I can clean up the exact coords.  I'm mainly wondering why `d3.mouse(this)` stopped working in the new context.  Any ideas?

Comment: I replaced `d3.mouse(this)` with `d3.mouse(document.getElementById("CON"))` where "CON" is the id of the svg element in which I was using the mouse.  This also eliminated the need to fix up the offsets.  Still curious though, why `this` didn't work.

Comment: the *this* you pass means something different in your outer wrapper function than it does to a direct object method. you can also use function.bind(this) to freeze a certain this value in place, but what you have now should work as expected.

Comment: ```event.x``` and ```event.y``` provides position relative to the topleft corner of the the page, not relative to the svg item. It is not equivalent to ```d3.mouse(this)``` which returns position relative to ```this``` topleft corner.